# Error creating an instance of a generic abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I am trying to instantiate an implementation of an abstract class and assign it to a variable of type of the abstract class:

```
CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<Control> creador = new CreadorUnilinea();
```

but I get the following compilation error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'WpfDiseniadorPruebas.Aplicacion.CreadorUnilinea' to 
    'WpfDiseniadorPruebas.Aplicacion.CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<System.Windows.Controls.Control>'
```

My question is, how can I do to generate an instance derived from the base class?

The base class and two of its implementations are defined below:

Base class:

```
public abstract class CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<TControl> where TControl: Control, new() {
    private const string PrefijoParaControles = "CTRL_";
    private const string PrefijoParaLayoutItems = "LI_";

    public virtual LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeId(int idDeElemento) {
        var campoConId = new LytCampoDeLayout {
            Id = idDeElemento,
            Tipo = LytTipoDelCampo.SIN_ESPEC,
            Texto = $"Elemento ID={idDeElemento}"
        };
        return this.CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(campoConId);
    }

    public virtual LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(LytCampoDeLayout campo) {
        var id = campo.Id;
        var texto = campo.Texto;
        var control = new TControl {
            Name = $"{PrefijoParaControles}{id}"
        };
        var layoutItem = new LayoutItem {
            Name = $"{PrefijoParaLayoutItems}{id}",
            Tag = campo,
            Label = texto,
            LabelPosition = LayoutItemLabelPosition.Top,
            Content = control
        };
        return layoutItem;
    }
}
```

The classes that inherit it:

```
public class CreadorUnilinea : CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<TextEdit> {
    public override LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeId(int idDeElemento) {
        var layoutItem = base.CrearAPartirDeId(idDeElemento);
        var tagDelLayoutItem = (LytCampoDeLayout)layoutItem.Tag;
        tagDelLayoutItem.Tipo = LytTipoDelCampo.UNI;

        return layoutItem;
    }

    public override LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(LytCampoDeLayout campo) {
        if (campo.Tipo != LytTipoDelCampo.UNI)
            throw new ArgumentException("El tipo del campo debe ser unilinea.", nameof(campo.Tipo));

        return base.CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(campo);
    }
}

public class CreadorSoloFecha : CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<DateEdit> {
    public override LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeId(int idDeElemento) {
        var layoutItem = base.CrearAPartirDeId(idDeElemento);
        var tagDelLayoutItem = (LytCampoDeLayout)layoutItem.Tag;
        tagDelLayoutItem.Tipo = LytTipoDelCampo.FECHA_SOLO;

        return layoutItem;
    }

    public override LayoutItem CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(LytCampoDeLayout campo) {
        if (campo.Tipo != LytTipoDelCampo.FECHA_SOLO)
            throw new ArgumentException("El tipo del campo debe ser solo fecha.", nameof(campo.Tipo));

        return base.CrearAPartirDeEntidadCampo(campo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea. It won’t work. A generic won’t be consider as the same type. E.g List<string> is a different type of List<int> there’s no way to get around it. However, it might be harder, but dun use generic be ur base class, try to implement ur base class as dynamic and handle all the type casting operation in it.

Comment: @cscmh99 The thing is that in my derived classes, DateEdit and TextEdit both derive from the Control class. My question is if it cannot be assigned as I did, that is
`CreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<Control> creador = new CreadorUnilinea();`

Comment: @Marlonchosky Are you able to introduce an interface `ICreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<out TControl>`? If you derive your base class from this covariant interface, then you will be able to use `ICreadorDeLayoutItemYControl<Control> creador = new CreadorUnilinea();`.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev interesting, let me try. Thank you!!

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Good answer, it works by adding a covariant interface. However, I changed the design of this part of my application because it was very confused. Thanks anyway!